# PHPExcel Accounting Formats

Tags: phpexcel

I'm working with PHPExcel and I'm trying to format a cell using Excel's built-in "Accounting" format.  I'm aware of the Format Code:

```
PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_CURRENCY_USD_SIMPLE
```

But this simply formats to two decimal places and adds a $ in front of the number.  The result I'm looking for is the right aligned cell with the $ on the left.  $0 values should be listed as "-" and negative values should be $ (1.11)

As far as I can tell there are no other currency formats in the documentation (though I may have missed it, this documentation is horrendous).  Am I looking in the wrong place?  Can this be achieved with regular cell formatting or is Excel doing something unique for Accounting?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I reverse engineered the format code from an existing spreadsheet using PHPExcel and got this:

```
_("$"* #,##0.00_);_("$"* \(#,##0.00\);_("$"* "-"??_);_(@_)
```

This is the code Excel places on the cell when you select the "Accounting" format... or click that "$" toolbar button in Excel 2007.

If you didn't need currency symbol :

```
->setFormatCode("_(* #,##0.00_);_(* \(#,##0.00\);_(* \"-\"??_);_(@_)");
```

Comment: This helped me a lot! Thanks!

Comment: how do you implement this?

Comment: @relipse -  `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A1")->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode("_(\"$\"* #,##0.00_);_(\"$\"* \(#,##0.00\);_(\"$\"* \"-\"??_);_(@_)");`

Comment: Could we get a breakdown of the expression and what each character does/means?

Comment: idk bout dat @MatthewGoheen, but i need without symbol and other answer still buggy for me, so i updated the answer like this `->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode("_(* #,##0.00_);_(* \(#,##0.00\);_(* \"-\"??_);_(@_)");`

Answer (score 7):

`$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C1')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode("#,##0.00");`

or use

`$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C1')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode("#.##0,00");`

Set in `getStyle` CELL.

Answer (score 3):

There are no other **pre-defined** formats beyond those listed in PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat, but you should be able to set the format code to any string that you could use when setting an MS Excel custom format...

e.g.

```
[green]$#,##0.00;[red]$(-#,##0.00)
```

As regards cell alignment, set this to right yourself, or don't set it at all.

Comment: I understand I can set the cell alignment and do conditional formatting on my end, but when MS Excel uses an 'accounting' format it aligns the currency sign ($, £, etc.) on the left and the rest of the cell on the right and handles the rest automagically.  Is this not a format that can be set with PHPExcel?

Comment: @epalla Standard MS Excel format mask would be "_-£* #,##0.00_-;-£* #,##0.00_-;_-£* "-"??_-;_-@_-" (using £ as the currency symbol) or something like "_-[$€-2] * #,##0.00_-;-[$€-2] * #,##0.00_-;_-[$€-2] * "-"??_-;_-@_-" (using a €)... these are just standard MS Excel formats, which will work perfectly with the Excel5 and Excel2007 writers... though they won't look as good if you use CSV or HTML or PDF writers