# PHPSpreadsheet accounting format

Tags: phpspreadsheet

Do someone know how to apply the equivalent to 'Accounting forma' in PHPSpreadsheet?

[image]

I found an [old Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669941/phpexcel-accounting-formats) mentioning how to do it with it's predecessor PHPExcel but when I try to create my own constant with that same value: ***("$"* #,##0.00*);*("$"* (#,##0.00);*("$"* "-"??*);*(@_)** I don't get the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry, but the answer was the same as the one for PHP Excel. It was the way I was accesing the constant what caused the problem (FORMAT_ACCOUNTING instead of self::FORMAT_ACCOUNTING)

For reference: you need to create your own constant:

```
const FORMAT_ACCOUNTING = '_("$"* #,##0.00_);_("$"* \(#,##0.00\);_("$"* "-"??_);_(@_)';
```

Answer (score -1):

To complement the answer, only you need to do this:

1. Find the file ***NumberFormat.php*** on the route `PHPspreadsheet\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat.php`.
2. Open the file.
3. Add this code on the class `const FORMAT_ACCOUNTING = '_("$"* #,##0.00_);_("$"* \(#,##0.00\);_("$"* "-"??_);_(@_)';`
4. By last, you need to call this format in your report, like this:

**Report File**

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('J')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_ACCOUNTING);
```

Or, you can do (an easy or short way), without to update or modified the file class:

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('J')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('_("$"* #,##0.00_);_("$"* \(#,##0.00\);_("$"* "-"??_);_(@_)');
```

Comment: Please never edit the contents of your vendor packages. This makes things very hard if you ever decide to update the package, or implement Composer.

Comment: Maybe I have omitted more details about what you propose, but it is a valid solution. But I also put another answer where you do not have to edit the packages of "vendor" but you give a format. You're right, regards.